# Compile error when using ffmpeg

Tags: macos, gcc, ffmpeg

I've found a strange problem during the compile of an example of ffmpeg in Qt Mac.

I have installed the ffmpeg library and I have tested the examples of this with cc and gcc compiler on the terminal, and I don't have any problem in the case of compile and run.

But when I call the library (ffmpeg are C library) in Qt for compile the same code of the example, the g++ compiler give me many error.

I have used this structure in the main.cpp code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>

extern "C" {
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/samplefmt.h>
#include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

#include <QDebug>
```

and the Compile Output gives me:

```
In file included from ../audvid/main.cpp:7:
/opt/local/include/libavutil/timestamp.h: In function 'char*
av_ts_make_string(char*, int64_t)':
/opt/local/include/libavutil/timestamp.h:48: warning: comparison
between signed and unsigned integer expressions
/opt/local/include/libavutil/timestamp.h:49: error: expected `)'
before 'PRId64' /opt/local/include/libavutil/timestamp.h:49: warning:
spurious trailing '%' in format
/opt/local/include/libavutil/timestamp.h:49: warning: too many
arguments for format /opt/local/include/libavutil/timestamp.h: At
global scope: /opt/local/include/libavutil/timestamp.h:68: error:
'AVRational' has not been declared
/opt/local/include/libavutil/timestamp.h: In function 'char*
av_ts_make_time_string(char*, int64_t, int*)':
/opt/local/include/libavutil/timestamp.h:70: warning: comparison
between signed and unsigned integer expressions
/opt/local/include/libavutil/timestamp.h:71: error: 'av_q2d' was not
declared in this scope ../audvid/main.cpp: In function 'int
decode_packet(int*, int)': ../audvid/main.cpp:50: error: cannot
convert 'AVRational*' to 'int*' for argument '3' to 'char*
av_ts_make_time_string(char*, int64_t, int*)' ../audvid/main.cpp:73:
error: cannot convert 'AVRational*' to 'int*' for argument '3' to
'char* av_ts_make_time_string(char*, int64_t, int*)'
../audvid/main.cpp:75: error: 'struct AVFrame' has no member named
'channels' ../audvid/main.cpp:84: error: 'struct AVFrame' has no
member named 'channels' ../audvid/main.cpp:90: error: 'struct AVFrame'
has no member named 'channels' ../audvid/main.cpp: In function 'int
open_codec_context(int*, AVFormatContext*, AVMediaType)':
../audvid/main.cpp:112: error: 'av_get_media_type_string' was not
declared in this scope ../audvid/main.cpp:123: error:
'av_get_media_type_string' was not declared in this scope
../audvid/main.cpp:129: error: 'av_get_media_type_string' was not
declared in this scope ../audvid/main.cpp: In function 'int
get_format_from_sample_fmt(const char**, AVSampleFormat)':
../audvid/main.cpp:152: warning: comparison between signed and
unsigned integer expressions ../audvid/main.cpp: In function 'int
main(int, char**)': ../audvid/main.cpp:239: error: invalid conversion
from 'void*' to 'uint8_t**' make: *** [main.o] Error 1 make: Leaving
directory
`/Users/polin/Desktop/audvid/audvid-build-    Qt_4_8_0_qt_everywhere_opensource_src_4_8_0_tp-Release'
10:44:37: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2. Error while
building/deploying project audvid (target: Qt 4.8.0
(qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.0-tp)) When executing step 'Make'
```

I don't understand if I make a mistake in the code or if I must change the Qt compiler? (and I don't know how can do this)

Comment: I removed the references to Qt as it has very little to do with anything. You're probably using Qt Creator, which is an IDE geared towards Qt.

Comment: @rubenvb .. Totally disagree .. many people land or could land here because they don't know its a "gcc" issue .. they just see it while compliling Qt/C++

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `libavutil/avutil.h` before `#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>`. Also you need to add `#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>`

Comment: The reason for the errors `'AVRational' has not been declared...` and `error: 'av_q2d' was not declared in this scope` is that you did not include `libavutil/avutil.h`. Write a new compiler output after correction

Answer (score 1):

Because ffmpeg is written in pure C. Some C99 design is incompatible with g++ compiler. So one way to solve it is to find where the "wrong" source codes are and replace them with C++ design style.
e.g.

```
av_get_bytes_per_sample( static_cast<AVSampleFormat>(format) )
#undef av_err2str
#define av_err2str(errnum) \
av_make_error_string((char*)__builtin_alloca(AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE), AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, errnum)
#undef av_ts2timestr
#define av_ts2timestr(ts, tb) \
av_ts_make_time_string((char*)__builtin_alloca(AV_TS_MAX_STRING_SIZE), ts, tb)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this leak the allocated memory?

Comment: Ahh, now I see, `alloca` allocates memory on stack. Clever!